# How to stop running Spark application?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I wrote a few Spark job in Java then submitted the jars with submit script.

```
bin/spark-submit --class "com.company.spark.jobName.SparkMain" --master local[*] /tmp/spark-job-1.0.jar
```

There will be a service and will run in same server. The service should stop the job when receive the stop command.

I have these information about job in service:

- SparkHome
- AppName
- AppResource
- Master uri
- app-id
- status

Is there any way to stop running spark job in java code.

Comment: You can use spark-launcher module of spark. More detailed: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you reviewed [the REST server](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/rest/RestSubmissionClient.scala#L45) and the ability to use `/submissions/kill/[submissionId]`? That seems like it would work for your need.

Comment: I am trying to use Rest Server with "/submissions/kill/[submissionId]" request. I tried app-id for kill the job but it doesn't work. How can i get submissionID ?